# eliminar la ultima palabra de una variable en este caso la palabra ( fin)

Tags: variables

```
var palabras ="";


 do {

   var cadena = prompt ("Porfabor intruduza cadenas")

   if  (palabras == "") {

     palabras = palabras + cadena;
   }

   else {

     palabras = palabras + " " + cadena;
   }

}
while (cadena != "fin") {



  document.write("Las cadenas escritas son : " +  palabras);
}
```

Comment: Por favor pon algo de texto para explicar tu situación y no solamente el codigo de tu problema así nos darás mas herramientas para ayudarte mas eficazmente.

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como lo tienes te sobran varias cosas:

1. El primer `if(palabras=="")` te sobra. Es mejor poner directamente `if(cadena!=="")` para concatenar el texto sólo si es distinto de vacío. Fíjate que es `cadena` y no `palabras` lo que estoy comparando porque palabras en ese punto siempre va a ser vacío por lo que nunca vas a entrar en el `if`. Aprende más `[aquí][1]` sobre los operadores en javascript.
2. Piensa que estás haciendo un bucle do-while por lo que lo mejor es declarar tus variables fuera del bucle.
3. Para eliminar el último elemento puedes primero transformar tu string a array con `split(" ")` (separamos por espacio vacío) y luego utilizar `splice()` y `join(" ")` para volver a unir tu array en un string separado por espacios en blanco. Otra opción sería utilizar un array directamente e ir haciendo `push()` con cada palabra que introduzca el usuario.

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
let palabras = "";
let cadena; 
    
do {       
  cadena = prompt ("Por favor, intruduzca cadenas. Para terminar escriba 'fin'");
   if(cadena !== "") {
     palabras = palabras + " " + cadena;
   }        
}
while (cadena.toLowerCase() !== "fin")

document.write("Las cadenas escritas son : " +  palabras.split(" ").splice(0,palabras.split(" ").length-1).join(" "));
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Kiko_L todo aclarado perfectamente .